# Why my title gives this render when it is in two lines?

Tags: html, css

I'm doing a list with a title, description and an icon for each list, but I have a problem in responsive.

Currently, everything is perfect, but when I reduce my window to see the result in responsive, I have this: http://screencast.com/t/NlT927iGb

When my title goes into two lines to have more space, my description is broken and is not properly aligned.

Here's my HTML code:

```
<div id="index-features">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <h5 id="feature-1" class="feature-title">Instant access</h5>
            <span id="feature-1-description" class="feature-description">After purchasing a style, there will be no waiting. Your account will be directly promoted in the "Customers" group and you will unlock access to all the features of the forum.</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h5 id="feature-2" class="feature-title">Compatibility with all browsers</h5>
            <span id="feature-2-description" class="feature-description">The styles are tested on all browsers to analyze any bugs and if we find, we correct them.</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h5 id="feature-3" class="feature-title">Modern techniques</h5>
            <span id="feature-3-description" class="feature-description">We use modern techniques (CSS3 gradients, etc.) to stand out from others.</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h5 id="feature-4" class="feature-title">Compatibility with the default XenForo products.</h5>
            <span id="feature-4-description" class="feature-description">The styles are worked not only for the forum software, but also for the default XenForo products (Media Gallery and Resource Manager).</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and my CSS code:

```
#index-features
{
    margin-top: 15px;
}

#index-features li
{
    border-bottom: #CCCCCC 1px solid;
    margin: 0 -20px 20px -20px;
    padding: 0 20px; 0 20px;
}

#index-features li:last-child
{
    border-bottom: none;
}

.feature-title:before
{
    content: "";
    float: left;
    background: url("../images/index-features-sprite.png") no-repeat;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

.feature-description
{
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 5px 0 20px 0;
}

#feature-1:before
{
    background-position: 0 0;
}

#feature-2:before
{
    background-position: 0 -32px;
}

#feature-3:before
{
    background-position: 0 -64px;
}
```

You can have a live preview here: nextgenfocus.com/test/

Don't forget to reduce your window to see the problem.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't have time now but will explain it when I return: `.feature-description { margin: 5px 0 20px 37px; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is because when you reduce the size of the screen it is pushing the text down below the bottom edge of the left image which was previously pushing the content to the right. Once your text goes below the image there is nothing pushing it away from the left border and so you get that effect. To counteract it simply add change this:

```
.feature-description
{
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 5px 0 20px 0;
}
```

to:

```
.feature-description {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 13px 0 20px 37px;
}
```

By adding a left margin you force the content to stay lined up with the title. The left margin value is found by adding the width of the image to the margin-right value on the image which is what determines how far from the left border your title is:

```
.feature-title:before
{
    content: "";
    float: left;
    background: url("../images/index-features-sprite.png") no-repeat;
    width: 32px;  // this value
    height: 32px;
    margin-right: 5px; // plus this value 
}
```

the `width` and `margin-right` of the image `.feature-title:before` are what determines where the `.feature-title` line starts. You need to explicitly match this margin in your `.feature-description`

Comment: Yes, I've already also used this solution, but I thought that there was a kind of thing for aligning text directly without having to add a margin. Thanks for the explanation.